# Getting on the value from the select object in React Select

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-select

Hello guys am a novice programmer with React creating my pioneer project. I have an issue that when i select an item from the React-Select dropdown and i submit. The whole object is posted as you can see in the sector formgroup i have posted below.

Attached also are screenshot for further illustrate the scenario. Looking forward to your response on this.

```js
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [sectors, setSectors] = useState('');
    const [selectedSector, setSelectedSector] = useState('');

    const { register, errors, watch, handleSubmit, control  } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        //createSchool();
        console.log(data);
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
        const getSectors = async () => {
          try {
            setIsLoading(true);       
            const allSectors = [
                { value: "Private", label: "Private" },
                { value: "Government Aided", label: "Government Aided" },
                { value: "Community", label: "Community" }
            ];
            const [{ value: firstSector } ] = allSectors;
            console.log(firstSector);
            setSectors(allSectors);
            setSelectedSector(firstSector);
            setIsLoading(false);
          } catch (error) {
            setSectors([]);
            setIsLoading(false);
          }
        };
      
        getSectors();
      }, []);
```

```js
<Form.Group>
                                    <Form.Label for="sector">Sector</Form.Label>
                                    <Controller
                                        control={control}
                                        name="sector"
                                        defaultValue=""
                                        value={selectedSector}
                                        onChange={(event) => setSelectedSector(event.target.value)}
                                        options={sectors}
                                        as={Select}
                                        />
                                    
                                    {errors.sector && (
                                        <p className="errorMsg">{errors.sector.message}</p>)} 
                                </Form.Group>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The whole **object** is occurring because each option has a object as value. When you trying to *event.target.value* that is equal to those option object. So what you have to do is use *event.target.value.value*.